# xlswrite in case of vectors

Tags: excel, matlab, export, cell

I have a .mat file which contains `titles={'time','data'}` and 2 column vectors:
`time=[1;2;3;4;5]` and `data=[10;20;30;40;50]`.

I created a new cell called table={'time','data';time data} and i used:

```
xlswrite(filename,table);
```

However, when i open the xlsx file it shows me only the titles and not showing the numbers.
I saw that xlswrite will show empty cell in case im trying to export more than 1 number in a cell.

Is there anything i can do to export the whole vector instead of writing each value in it's cell?

The final result that i tried to get is like this:

```
time   data
1       10
2       20
3       30
4       40
5       50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options. Usually what I do is break it into two `xlswrite` calls, one for the header and one for the data.

```
titles = {'time','data'};
time = [1;2;3;4;5];
data = [10;20;30;40;50];

xlswrite('myfile.xlsx', titles, 'Sheet1', 'A1');
xlswrite('myfile.xlsx', [time, data], 'Sheet1', 'A2');
```

Alternatively, if you have R2013b or newer you can also use the [`table`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) builtin, which has its [own method for writing out data](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html). With the same sample data:

```
mytable = table(time, data, 'VariableNames', titles);
writetable(mytable, 'myfile.xlsx');
```