# Inserting data into a particular column of an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, matlab

I am trying to inset data into an Excel sheet with:

```
clc
clear all
%% INPUTS
% We have two column data and it has headers in the first row.
% That is why we read the data from A2 to B32.
 A=xlsread('mysheet.xlsx','B2:C41');
% disp ('The data read from the excel spreadsheet is')
% disp(A)
% disp('  ')
%% SOLUTION
% Finding the number of rows and columns
sizem=size(A);
rows_A=sizem(1);
cols_A=sizem(2);
% Assigning the scores to a vector called score
for i=1:1:rows_A
    score(i)=A(i,1)+A(i,2);
end

%% OUTPUT
disp('  ')
disp (score)
```

The header name 'Totals' is being inserted but not the data. All the data is stored in the vector `score`.

Could someone suggest what to do in order to insert data in to that particular column 'E1'? And I am able to insert static vectors as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31028741/1662775) in the column but not the dynamically increase one like the variable 'score'

Comment: I even tried deleting the duplicate code but it still doesn;t work